# Display a .txt file in alphabetical order in python

Tags: python, alphabetical, alphabetical-sort

I have this .txt file

```
Sam : 6
Peter : 9
Hubert: 4
Daniel : 2
Richard : 1
David : 8
Jesus : 10
```

What I want to do is (in my program) print out this .txt file but in alphabetical order. So my output would look like this:

```
Daniel : 2
David : 8
Hubert: 4
Jesus : 10
Peter : 9
Richard : 1
Sam : 6
```

How can I do this in python? Could you show me how? Any answers and feedback are well-appreciated, and it would be great if any possible solutions are as simple and basic as possible (I'm new to python, so no overcomplicated / abstract code please). Thanks!

Comment: Your question shows that there are blank lines between every non-blank line. Do you want those blank lines sorted too?

Comment: Whoops - I'll have to change that! My actual file looks identical to the above, but just without the lines / spaces in between. Basically, I just want code which will print (display) out my file; but just in alphabetical order. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(''.join(sorted(open('file.txt'))), end='')
```

Alternatively:

```
for line in sorted(open('file.txt')):
    print(line, end='')
```

Why the `end=''`? Because the `line` already contains a newline character so we do not want `print` to print another one.

The maybe not so obvious trick is that a file object returns (yields) lines when iterated. You can do `for line in f:` or `list(f)` to read all lines from a file where `f` is a file object.

Comment: Great! I'll give this a go and see if it works. I'll up mark it as a solution if it works straight away. Thanks!

Comment: FANTASTIC! I just tried this in my code... it works perfectly! Thank you so much.